# iframe-resizer Sending Message, but not receiving

Tags: javascript, iframe, moodle, iframe-resizer

I'm using https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer.

iframeResizer.min.js is in the parent page and

iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js is in the child

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  iFrameResize({log:true,checkOrigin:false});

});
```

the logging seems to show the messaging starting OK - it starts like this

[iFrameSizer][Host page: contentframe] [iFrame.onload] Sending msg to iframe[contentframe] (contentframe:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:bodyOffset:null:null:0:false:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *  iframeResizer.min.js:11:62

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] Initialising iFrame (http://xxxxxxx/)

iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] TargetOrigin for parent set to: *  iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] HTML & body height set to "auto"  iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] Enable public methods  iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] Add event listener: Animation Start

and ends with

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] Trigger event lock on  iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] Sending message to host page (contentframe:655:748:init)  iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] Trigger event lock off   iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][contentframe] --  iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js:9:693

[iFrameSizer][Host page: contentframe] No response from iFrame. Check iFrameResizer.contentWindow.js has been loaded in iFrame

I'm trying to use this in Moodle if that makes a difference?

Any ideas what can block the receiving of the message on the parent?
On the demo page the messgaing seems to result in a message back to the parent like this

[iFrameSizer][Host page] Received: [iFrameSizer]iFrameResizer0:284:1588:init

But I don't seem to be getting a received message (and so it's not resizing the parent)

Answer (score 2):

It's to do with requirejs.

I ended up including a js file with the following code in it:

```
require(['/theme/elegance/javascript/iframeResizer.min.js'], function (iFrameResize) {

iFrameResize({log:true,checkOrigin:false});

});
```

This seems to register the iFrameResize object in the way that I need.